# How does Pragma (OMP) affect the measurement of time taken to execute a piece of code?

Tags: c, time

I am trying to measure the time taken to execute a piece of code under different conditions. I provide a number n, and the program prints the time it took to execute a loop n times. But the displayed time seems to be inaccurate when using with #pragma directive.

I have tried with and without #pragma directive.

```
#include <threads.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

void loopy(int);
void runloop(int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("The number entered is :: %d\n",num);

    displayTimeTaken(loopy,num);

}

void loopy(int num){
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)for(int j=0;j<num;j++);
}

void displayTimeTaken(void *function(), int num){
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    start = clock();

    function(num);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken is :: %10fs for the number %d\n ", cpu_time_used,num);
}
```

The results in my CPU for input 100000 is ::
(Without Parallelism)

> Time taken is :: 24.632967s for the number 100000

The real time as recorded in my clock is also 24 secs.

So far so good.

(With Parallelism)

> Time taken is :: 24.408596s for the number 100000

But the real time it took was around 8 seconds!
I checked the code multiple times but it makes no sense for me how pragma is affecting the displayed time. I ran the gdb and found out that the program is launching 3 threads.

```
The number entered is :: 100000
[New Thread 0x7ffff7d79700 (LWP 8761)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff7578700 (LWP 8762)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff6d77700 (LWP 8763)]
Time taken is ::  24.177702s for the number 100000
 [Thread 0x7ffff6d77700 (LWP 8763) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff7578700 (LWP 8762) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff7d79700 (LWP 8761) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 8760) exited normally]
```

My first theory was therefore, somehow, the time taken by individual threads are being added up. But again, it makes no sense for me.

I would be happy if someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`clock()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock) returns the approximate processor time used by the process.  This can be larger or smaller than the real time (sometimes referred to as "wall time") used for execution.

As an alternative, you can use the `time` function, but this generally only has a resolution of one second.

For higher resolution wall clocks, you'll need to use something system specific (e.g., `clock_gettime` on systems that provide the POSIX headers, `GetTickCount` on Windows).